# Microsoft Ribbon´s RibbonWindow disables visual styles

Tags: wpf, ribbon, ribboncontrolslibrary

i just tried to use "RibbonWindow" to integrate my ribbon menu into the window.
But now, if i start the program, it looks like punched with a glitchy classic-style.

This is, how it should look like:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/594/pfgok.png/

and this is how it looks like:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/840/pfgfail.png/

Why is this so?
Thanks :)

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I´m not sure... i think i just created a whole new window in the solution explorer. at least it works now. But i´m not sure what the problem was, sorry -.-'

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason. This is a known defect in the pre .Net 4.5 release. Details can be found on connect.microsoft.com:

[.NET 4.5 WPF RibbonWindow broken in VS2012](https://web.archive.org/web/20130621080517/http://connect.microsoft.com:80/VisualStudio/feedback/details/747820/net-4-5-wpf-ribbonwindow-broken-in-vs2012)

This should be fixed in the final release.

Answer (score -1):

Try setting Window Class to RibbonWindow as in example